# ADF - Run an activity if any one of a set of activities fail and capture failed activity details in that activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently I am running one generic activity when any of the activities in the pipeline fail based on the answer provided in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/208812/adf-run-an-activity-if-any-one-of-a-set-of-activit

But I want to identify which activity is failed in pipeline across 30 activities in generic activity.

We can write 30 if conditions like below in pipeline expression builder but I am looking for more optimized solution.

[image]

Do we have any solution to identify which activity is failed if we have large number of activities..?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have any solution to identify which activity is failed if we have large number of activities..?

You can use an **Execute Pipeline** activity for this. Give all your activities with certain names in a pipeline. Take another pipeline with Execute pipeline activity and give your pipeline to it. On the Faiilure of this activity add your Generic activity.

In this approach,

- **The child pipeline(your pipeline) flow will stop on the first failure of any activity and Execute pipeline activity also fails**.
- Now you can execute your Generic activity. By using this approach, it does not matter whatever the pipeline flow whether simple or complicated because it identifies first failed activity.

But one thing is you need to make sure that all activities should execute only on the success of previous activities.

This is the sample demonstration for it.

My sample child pipeline with activities `Mylookup`, `activity1`, `activity2`. Here `Mylookup` designed to be failed.

[image]

And this is the failure message for it.

[image]

We can get the name and error details of the above failed activity after Execute pipeline activity in Parent pipeline using below approach.

Here Execute pipeline activity will give the error details like this for any failed activity of the child pipeline.

[image]

So, extract the activity name from the above using below expression.

```
@substring(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message, add(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'target'),7), sub(sub(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'failed'),1),add(indexOf(activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message,'target'),7)))
```

**Failed activity name:**
For sample, I have stored this in a set variable

[image]

Extract the error details JSON of activity using `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').error` expression and for error message use this `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').error.message`.

You can combine the activity name and error details as per your requirement in your generic activity which should execute on the failure of Execute pipeline activity.